# QtCreator highlight for alternative operators: "not", "and" and "or" in C++ code?

Tags: c++11, qt-creator

I'm using QtCreator 4.6.2 for C++ code, it is possible to get highlight for "not", "and" and "or" keywords?

Comment: Yes, just spell them `!`, `&&` and `||` like everyone else does :-)

Comment: Good one! I find a "not" much clearly visible then an "!". And the other two eliminate the possibility of writing the bitwise operators instead of the the logical one.